# NameError in UsersController#index uninitialized constant UsersController::User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I'm new to Rails and continue getting this error. I've double checked my syntax and everything seems to be fine. I've included what I believe to be the pertinent files but let me know if you need more info.

controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users, status: :ok
end

def show
    render json: @user
end

def create

    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    render json: @user, status: :created
end

def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render json: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def destroy
    @user = User.where(id: params[:id]).first
    if @user.destroy
        head(:ok)
    else
        head(:unprocessable_entity)
    end
end

private 

def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
```

end

models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_password
validates :email, presence: true
has_many :reviews, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :albums
```

end

config/routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "static#home"
  resources :users
  get "*path", to: "fallback#index", constraints: ->(req) { !req.xhr? && req.format.html? }
end
```

Comment: try replacing `User` with `::User` . lets see if error goes.

Comment: The code here won't actually reproduce the issue so we can't actually tell you whats wrong. You need to double check file names and other sources of "slop errors" like for example unsaved files or VC related issues.

Comment: @dileepnandanam thats a fools errand since Ruby walks up the module nesting to Object anyways looking for the constant. The reason the error message is `uninitialized constant UsersController::User` is because that is the module nesting where it started looking for the constant.

Answer (score 0):

The routes file is irrelevent here. It feels like the User model just cannot be found at all. Try just

```
User.new
```

in the console. If it can't be found perhaps the model is in the wrong location. e.g. is it in app/models/user.rb ? If it is what happens if you

```
require './app/models/user'
```

Anything like a syntax error, etc?

Answer (score 0):

In rails 7 when we're trying to create a new Controller without creating its Model. I was facing the same issue.

**NameError in UsersController#index uninitialized constant UsersController::User**

Just need to add skip_load_and_authorize_resource in the controller

```
 skip_load_and_authorize_resource
```

Let supose we have a controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  skip_load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
   @user = User.all
  end

end
```